# Adding KML layer using ArcGIS API for Silverlight?

Tags: kml, arcgis-silverlight-api

I am trying to create a map which will include radar rainfall data in a KML format. How can I easily do this using the Silverlight API (the version doesn't matter)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [KmlLayer class](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/2.1/apiref/api_start.htm?ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources.KmlLayer.html) has been added at to the Toolkit at version 2.1, which is currently in beta.

Comment: The Silverlight 2.1 API has been released. Here's [What's New](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/help/index.html#/What_s_new_in_2_1/016600000025000000/) (including information about the KML layer feature).

Comment: The ESRI API is now at 3.0. The KmlLayer has changed. More up-to-date (and thorough) documentation [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources.KmlLayer.html).

Answer (score 6):

KML layers are not natively supported in AGS web APIs, AFAIK. There is a code sample that you can get inspiration from in the Resource Center: http://resources.esri.com/arcgisserver/apis/silverlight/index.cfm?fa=codeGalleryDetails&scriptID=16487